# jQuery $.post() Unable to Upload File Along with Form Data

Tags: jquery

I am trying to upload a file along with other form elements. Code sample given at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6ksyrqe/)

I have been getting several errors trying in different ways.

When I use `$form = new FormData($(this))` I get the following error, 
`TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.`

When I just use `$form = $(this)` then the form works but file does not get uploaded.

HTML code is:

```
<div class="form_result"></div>
<form action="" method="post" id="main_form_new" name="main_form_new" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="uname">Username</label>
                <select tabindex="52" class="form-control" name="uname" id="uname">
                    <option value="1">user 1</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pay">Payment Method</label>
                <select tabindex="55" class="form-control" name="pay" id="pay">
                    <option value="1">Online Transfer</option>
                    <option value="2">Wire Transfer</option>
                    <option value="3">IMPS</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="uproof">Upload Proof</label>
                <input tabindex="56" class="browsefile" id="uproof" name="uproof" size="20" type="file" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bankn"> Bank Name</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="57" maxlength="120" id="bankn" name="bankn" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="transid">Trans ID</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="61" maxlength="100" id="transid" name="transid" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button tabindex="64" type="submit" id="btn-progress" class="btn btn-primary sbbtn"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save Changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery Code goes like this:

```
$(function() {
    function formSubmitHandler(options) {
        return function (e) {
            var $form = new FormData($(this)),
                $submit = $(options.submit),
                $alert = $(options.alert);

            e.preventDefault();

            $alert.fadeOut();
            $submit.html('Saving Changes...').prop({disabled: true});

            $.post(options.url, $form.serialize())
            .done(function (data) {
                $alert.html(data).fadeIn();
                $form.trigger('reset');
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $alert.html(textStatus).fadeIn();
                console.log(arguments);
            })
            .always(function () {
                $submit.html('Save Changes').prop({disabled: false});
            });
        };
    }

    $('#main_form_new').submit(formSubmitHandler({
        url: 'ajax/category.php',
        submit: '.sbbtn',
        alert: '.form_result'
    }));
});
```

How can I upload a file along with other form elements? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `new FormData()` must be the DOM element for the form, but `$(this)` is a jQuery object containing the element. You should just use `this`.

You can't use `$form.serialize()`. `serialize()` is a jQuery method, but `$form` is a `FormData` object. Just use `$form` as the data argument.

But you can't post a `FormData` using the simple format of `$.post`, you need to use either `$.ajax` or the form of `$.post` that takes a settings object as the argument (available after 1.12 or 2.2)`

```js
$(function() {
  function formSubmitHandler(options) {
    return function(e) {
      var $form = new FormData(this),
        $submit = $(options.submit),
        $alert = $(options.alert);

      e.preventDefault();

      $alert.fadeOut();
      $submit.html('Saving Changes...').prop({
        disabled: true
      });

      $.ajax({
          url: options.url,
          type: "POST",
          data: $form,
          processData: false
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          $alert.html(data).fadeIn();
          $form.trigger('reset');
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $alert.html(textStatus).fadeIn();
          console.log(arguments);
        })
        .always(function() {
          $submit.html('Save Changes').prop({
            disabled: false
          });
        });
    };
  }

  $('#main_form_new').submit(formSubmitHandler({
    url: 'ajax/category.php',
    submit: '.sbbtn',
    alert: '.form_result'
  }));
});
```

Comment: @KevinB So it's basically the same as `$.ajax` except it defaults to `type: "POST"`?

Comment: am getting an error using this, TypeError: $submit.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: `$submit = $(options.submit),` true, this is the error which I get when I submit the form

Comment: I don't see `addEventListener` anywhere in the code. What line is getting that error?

Comment: jquery.min.js:2:70467 on firefox

Comment: The error is happening inside jQuery, but the variable name is `$submit`?

Comment: My mistake, I was validating the form with validate plugin with `$form.validate()`, Thank you so much. Unfortunately I cant upvote as my reputation is lesser than 15. Thanks again so much.

Comment: Accepting the answer is better than upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to create a new FormData and append each one the other elements, as well as the file.

```
// Create the form that we will be sending
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("productMedia", fileToUpload);
formData.append("uname", userName);
formData.append("pay", pay); 
// Other elements you need to append.  

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/category.php',
    data: formData,
    // Tell jQuery not to process data or not to worry about content-type
    // You *must* include these options in order to send MultipartFile objects
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'POST'
}
```

This code will send the file with whatever other element you append. This is the way I have always done with Spring, but it shouldn't differ since is the same type of request.

Comment: POST is never cached, you don't need `cache: false`

Comment: Where do you set `fileToUpload`?

Comment: @AlainCruz Thanks, I cannot use this in as a common function for multiple forms on entire site. As it keeps changing the form elements.

Comment: @Barmar depends totally on how they are managing the files. If they get it from a input, is just as simple as getting it from that input `var fileToUpload = filesInput.files[0]`.

Comment: He posted his code, why don't you show how to get it?

Comment: `$("#uproof")[0].files[0]`

Comment: `formData.append("uproof", $("#uproof")[0].files[0])`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see `#uproof` being the file input. That is why I didn't add it.